# MySQL Query Coalesce with Inner Join

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm still pretty new to doing this, so I'm not entirely sure it's possible.

I have two databases and I'd like to run one query pulling from both- locating where

```
database1.table1.firstname + database1.table1.lastname = database2.table2.name
```

Is this possible?

I thought I could do something like

```
SELECT
    COALESCE(firstname + ' ' + lastname, firstname, lastname) Name 
FROM database1.table1
INNER JOIN database1.table1, database2.table2
WHERE
    Name = table2.name;
```

Is this possible? Or can joins only be performed on tables in the same databases?

Comment: What do you mean by "two databases"? Are you talking about two schemas in a single MySQL instance, or two separate MySQL instances?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any MySQL query can only be run on the same database, you must perform both queries from separate connections, then merge the data.

Answer (score 0):

Your join syntax is not correct.  I think you mean something like:

```
SELECT COALESCE(firstname + ' ' + lastname, firstname, lastname) Name 
FROM database1.table1 t1 inner join
     database2.table2 t2 
     on  COALESCE(t1.firstname + ' ' + t1.lastname, t1.firstname, t1.lastname) = t2.name
```